# How to compare lists in Python for partial matches?

Tags: python, list, comparison

I apologise if this question is badly phrased.

My script is running comparisons on trade messages, written as string values, and I wish to see if there are fields appearing in one messages, but not another. An example of the two messages being used are:

```
msg1 = ['35=D', '52=20160429', '11=0001A', '44=440', '15=EUR']
msg2 = ['35=D', '52=20160428', '11=0001B', '44=439', '15=EUR']
```

To compare the lists, I am using:

```
result = [o for o in a if o not in b]
```

Right now, my script is providing me with elements that do not *exactly* match, so for example:

```
nonmatches = ['52=20160428', '11=0001B', '44=439']
```

This will not work for me, as the tags are still present in both messages. So my question is - how would I compare the two lists after the first three characters of each element?

Comment: use slicing `i[3:]==j[3:]`

Comment: So the expected output for your sample data is `['0001B', '0001A', '440', '20160429', '20160428', '439']`?

Comment: @timgeb No, the expected output would be nothing, since the first 3 characters of each element (the tags) are present in both lists.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thank you, that seems to be what I was looking for. If you would like to write a formal answer, I will check it as the right answer.

Comment: @User588233 no problm, just give the credits to the  correct answerer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @avinash said, use slicing:

```
result = [o for o in msg1 if o[3:] not in [field[3:] for field in msg2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that a list representation is the best container for your data? Perhaps you should use a dict

```
msg1 = ['35=D', '52=20160429', '11=0001A', '44=440', '15=EUR']
msg2 = ['35=D', '52=20160428', '11=0001B', '44=439', '15=EUR']

d1 = {key:value for key,value in [item.split('=',1) for item in msg1]}
d2 = {key:value for key,value in [item.split('=',1) for item in msg2]}
```

Now your data is stored in a dict

```
print(d1)
# {'15': 'EUR', '44': '440', '11': '0001A', '35': 'D', '52': '20160429'}

print (d1.keys())
# dict_keys(['15', '44', '11', '35', '52'])
```

Now you can use set operations which will perform better than @Phillip-Martin 's answer above.

Eg:

```
# All different keys
d1.keys() ^ d2.keys()

# Keys in d1 not in d2
d1.keys() - d2.keys()

# Keys in d2 not in d1
d2.keys() - d1.keys()
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand what your mean. Do you want find different element in msg1.
I provide my answer here.

```
In [21]: msg1 = ['35=D', '52=20160429', '11=0001A', '44=440', '15=EUR']

In [22]: msg2 = ['35=D', '52=20160428', '11=0001B', '44=439', '15=EUR']

In [23]: [o for o in msg1 if o not in msg2]
Out[23]: ['52=20160429', '11=0001A', '44=440']
```